# Using an existing relation HAS-MANY on a criteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i'm having some problems using a custom made function to search specific data from my database.

I have TableA(id,....) and TableB(id, tablea_id, userid,...)

Model TableA has the following relation code:

'relation_name' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TableB', 'tablea_id')

I need to create a custom made function to query TableA and give me results that exist on TableA that contain a certain userid on TableB data, also TableB is related to TableA from tablea_id field.

I found the solution for my problem by using this code:

```
        public function findABCD($user_id)
    {
              $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
              $criteria->join = 'left join TableB on t.id=TableB.tablea_id';
              $criteria->condition = "TableB.userid = ".$user_id;
              return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
                      'criteria'=>$criteria,
              ));
    }
```

This works, but I'm not taking advantage of the relation that I have created earlier.
Any ideas of what I need to use?

I tested a lot of things but I'm receiving an SQL error.

This is what I have tested earlier (instead of the criteria Join and the Condition):

```
$criteria->with=array('relation_name');
$criteria->condition = "relation_name.userid= ".$user_id;
//this does not work as well
//$criteria->condition = "TableB.userid= ".$user_id;
```

The error is this:

```
SQL: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'relation_name.userid' in 'where clause'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should really read the [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/275/how-to-write-secure-yii-applications/#hh11) on how to properly escape your SQL queries. What you're doing here is extremely hazardous.

Comment: this is just an example, but if you are asking I have in place validation for my userid, I also don't allow any user to delete/edit content that I don't want to. But that's another story. Thanks for the info btw. Any ideas on the problem that i'm facing?

Comment: It's quite hard to debug an ORM unless you have a log of the actual queries being executed. It looks like your `with` call isn't joining the table in as you expect.

Comment: What I mean is that Yii has a facility for properly escaping values that you should make use of. Doing string concatenation of potentially user-provided values (e.g. query string parameters) is flirting with disaster. `array("TableB.userid" => $user_id)` is immeasurably better than `"TableB.userid = ".$user_id`.

Comment: have you tried with `$criteria->together=true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this kind of joins with ActiveRecord queries, not sure if it will work for CActiveDataProvider:

```
$criteria->with = array(
    'relation_name' => array(
        'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN',
        'on'       => 'user_id = :user_id',
        'params'   => array( 'user_id' => $userId )
    )
);

$criteria->together = true;
```